# explain java compile order

Tags: java, jvm, singleton

`v2` is null when it enters A's c'tor at the first time, but if I put `v2`'s declaration & initialization before `instance` it will have a value; why is this?

```
public class A {

    private static final String v1 = new String(new byte[]{'a', 'b'});

    private static A instance = new A();

    private static final String v2 = new String(new byte[]{'b', 'c'});

    private A() {
        System.out.printf("A c'tor\tv1 [%s]\tv2 [%s]\n", v1, v2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start main");
        new A();
        System.out.println("end main");
    }
}
```

output:

```
    A c'tor v1 [ab] v2 [null]
    start main
    A c'tor v1 [ab] v2 [bc]
    end main
```

Also, if I change `v2`'s initialization to instead be:

```
private static final String v2 = "ab";
```

it does initialize `v2`, and the output is:

```
A c'tor v1 [ab] v2 [ab]
start main
A c'tor v1 [ab] v2 [ab]
end main
```

**Edit**

another test for the second part:

```
public class A {

    private static final String v1 = new String(new byte[]{'a', 'b'});

    private static transient A instance = new A();

    private static final String v2 = new String(new byte[]{'b', 'c'});
    private static final String v3 = new String("ab");
    private static final String v4 = "ab";

    private A() {
        System.out.printf("A c'tor\tv1 [%s] v2 [%s] v3 [%s] v4 [%s]\n", v1, v2, v3, v4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start main");
        new A();
        System.out.println("end main");
    }
}
```

output:

```
A c'tor v1 [ab] v2 [null] v3 [null] v4 [ab]
start main
A c'tor v1 [ab] v2 [bc] v3 [ab] v4 [ab]
end main
```

Comment: Your static variables are being referenced line by line?  Hence v1 is set, A is created (with v2 still null), and v2 is set.

Comment: This code looks pretty straightforward and matches exactly to what you would expect. You can just debug the code and see what is executed in which order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static variables are initialized in the order they appear in the source file when class A is initialized (before `main` is executed).

- first v1
- then instance (which prints `A c'tor v1 [ab] v2 [null]` since its initialization involves creating an instance of A) - it is initialized before `v2`, which is why `v2` is still `null`.
- then v2

After they are initialized, the `main` method is executed, and produces the next 3 output lines. The creation of the new instance of `A` inside the `main` method produces a different output than the previous constructor call, since at this point both `v1` and `v2` are initialized.

EDIT :

Regarding your updated question :

If you follow the [initialization procedure in JLS 12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> 6. Otherwise, record the fact that initialization of the Class object for C is in progress by the current thread, and release LC. Then, **initialize the final class variables and fields of interfaces** whose values are **compile-time constant expressions.**
>
> ...
>
> 9. Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, **in textual order**, as though they were a single block.

As you can see, the final static variables whose values are [compile-time constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) are initialized before the rest of the static variables. Therefore changing the value of `v2` to the constant `"ab"` causes `v2` to be initialized before the `instance` variable, which explains the different output.

Comment: I would accept this message but just change v2 value to "ab"
private static final String v2 = "ab";
 and it will have value, can you explain this ?

Comment: @JimWest That would make v2 a constant, and if I remember correctly, constants are initialized earlier. I'll have to look it up in the JLS.

Comment: Toda @Eran, I added another example hope it helps.