# Static nested Class in java

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public class LinkedList { 

    Node head; // head of list 

    // Linked list Node. 
    // This inner class is made static 
    // so that main() can access it 
     static class Node { 

        int data; 
        Node next; 

        // Constructor 
        Node(int d) 
        { 
            data = d; 
            next = null; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I read about static inner class that it is like normal class.

In this  I am not understanding how **Node head** is called even before declaring static inner class ?

Is static inner class compiled first because of that outer class know about the inner class even before declaring it?

Comment: You're not "calling" (as you put it) anything. Instead you are telling the compiler about a new variable `head`, which is of type `Node`. Later you go on to tell the compiler what a `Node` actually is. This would fail in C, but works in Java (as well as any other reasonably modern language).

Comment: Maybe you can read this to clear your understanding - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compilation-execution-java-program/

Comment: if it is static it is not nested. But standalone(like if it was in a seperate file) . The produced *.class files count.

Comment: The sequence of members within a class is irrelevant. It's the statements within methods that need to be in sequence.

Comment: @fatcook make that an answer so that I can +1 it

Comment: @fatcook Its means first "head " is inserted into symbol table, then compiler does name resolution, type checking and constant folding. Is it correct?

Comment: @useruser , that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And as mentioned in [Java Compilation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Compilation):

> In Java, if you have used any reference to any other java object, then the class for that object will be automatically compiled, if that was not compiled already. These automatic compilations are nested, and this continues until all classes are compiled that are needed to run the program. So it is usually enough to compile only the high level class, since all the dependent classes will be automatically compiled.

So, in general you are right.

What about reasons for using nested classes? The [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) Oracle tutorial says:

> Compelling reasons for using nested classes include the following:
>
> It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one
>   place: If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is
>   logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting
>   such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.
>
> It increases encapsulation: Consider two top-level classes, A and B,
>   where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared
>   private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared
>   private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden
>   from the outside world.
>
> It can lead to more readable and maintainable code: Nesting small
>   classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is
>   used.

This is true for all nested classes including static.

Answer (score 0):

The static components of a class are always compiled before the instance components of a class. The compilation happens from top to bottom as you think but multiple times for different kind of components (static blocks, constants, instance variables, constructor,...)

This answer gives another good example of that : [explain java compile order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439450/explain-java-compile-order)

Comment: i defined static block and instance block in outer and inner class, outer class static and instance run before inner class

Comment: How can you be so sure it runs before the inner class?

Comment: it means static nested class will be loaded first?

Comment: Yes indeed, the static nested class will be loaded first. Otherwise, you would have a big problem as you imagine 

Comment: public class LinkedList { 

 Node head; 
static{
  System.out.println("outer");
}
 
 static class Node { 
static{
  System.out.println("inner");
}
      
  int data; 
  Node next; 

  
  Node(int d) 
  { 
   data = d; 
   next = null; 
  } 
 }

Comment: if static nested class will be loaded first, then static block should be called of inner class, but the output I am getting is outer class static block then inner class static block.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a variable(Not calling) of type Node, then compiler look for the type Node. As you defined Node as static inner class(or inner class) the compiler come to know what node really is.
The order of members in java class is irrelevant.